# Docusign recipient status

Tags: java, xml, api, docusignapi

Is it possible to get the status for each recipient of a DocuSign document via the API? What would be the xml/java to get the status for the recipients? I send the envelope with e-mails of different people but when I use the process described here http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeRecipientStatus there does not appear to be a place to specify which recipient to check the status of.

This would an example of what I'm looking for.

Document xxxxxxxxx
Recipient 1 Sent
Recipient 2 Signed on mm/dd/yyyy
Recipient 3 declined on mm/dd/yyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response to a DocuSign REST API "Get Envelope Recipient Status" call (GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients) will contain recipient status information for all recipients of an Envelope.  Pages 145-146 of the DocuSign REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) shows an example request and response (in JSON format).

Here's a sample response body for an envelope that has 4 recipients:
1) Jane signed/completed the envelope (routing order #1).
2) John signed/completed the envelope (routing order #2).
3) Jimmy received a copy of the envelope, as a Carbon Copy recipient (routing order #3).
4) Abe declined the envelope (routing order #4).

```
{
"signers": [
    {
        "signInEachLocation": "false",
        "name": "Abe Miller",
        "email": "emailAbe@outlook.com",
        "recipientId": "ea3362b6-cf00-4797-8cfb-56ca09b988a8",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "5b97e1be-3cea-49fb-a1c3-b77890b0b154",
        "routingOrder": "4",
        "status": "declined",
        "declinedDateTime": "2013-09-23T19:28:40.7670000Z",
        "declinedReason": "I don't want to sign."
    },
    {
        "signInEachLocation": "false",
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "email": "emailJane@outlook.com",
        "recipientId": "54fb0d38-7c60-4d37-976a-6c72ea2ce32d",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "17f820b1-f2a0-455a-88c2-e356a9c6914b",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "status": "completed",
        "signedDateTime": "2013-09-23T19:27:54.2330000Z",
        "deliveredDateTime": "2013-09-23T19:27:49.9900000Z"
    },
    {
        "signInEachLocation": "false",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "emailJohn@outlook.com",
        "recipientId": "78ef67bf-8795-4026-a57e-63ec960eb5a4",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "03c8a856-c0ae-41bf-943d-ac6e92db66a8",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "status": "completed",
        "signedDateTime": "2013-09-23T19:28:11.6900000Z",
        "deliveredDateTime": "2013-09-23T19:28:06.4170000Z"
    }
],
"agents": [],
"editors": [],
"intermediaries": [],
"carbonCopies": [
    {
        "name": "Jimmy Adams",
        "email": "emailJimmy@outlook.com",
        "recipientId": "afc51052-85e9-4575-8c06-b0f87c1a5d8b",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "7a64f726-8985-490b-9e94-04e54292f53c",
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "status": "completed",
        "deliveredDateTime": "2013-09-23T19:28:21.3600000Z"
    }
],
"certifiedDeliveries": [],
"inPersonSigners": [],
"recipientCount": "4"
}
```

By iterating through the recipients of each type in the response (signers, agents, editors, intermediaries, carbonCopies, certifiedDeliveries, inPersonSigners), you can access status information for each individual recipient.

(Note:  if you're using the DocuSign REST API, I'd recommend that you consider using JSON instead of XML.  While the DocuSign REST API ***technically*** supports both JSON and XML, the documentation available for using XML with the REST API is extremely limited -- you'll save yourself time and frustration by using JSON instead of XML, since a majority of the code samples and documentation DocuSign produces is in JSON.)